# Analog story, 1980s, Crisis at facility that uses rotational motion for storing energy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a story almost certainly from Analog, circa 1980 or so. To balance supply and demand, surplus energy is stored as rotational energy - a large cart rotates on the inside of a hemispherical dome, moving faster when more energy is coming in than going out, and being slowed to draw more power off.  An accident or terrorist attack damages the device, preventing power from being drawn off (I think) leading to a dangerous situation - leaving the heroes to have to try to repair the thing while its moving very fast.  I believe the main character had a child who was somehow involved or endangered by the situation.  Seems very much like a Timothy Zahn story, in my memory.

Comment: I get the "power" part of your title, but I don't see anything game-related to explain the "power leveling."

Comment: I've clarified (I hope); I meant "power leveling" in a non-game context.

Comment: Sound similar to [flywheel batteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flywheel#Superflywheel)! Unclear what aspect of the story is science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: @Lexible if the story is about a fictional flywheel that is more advanced than any real one - it would be hard science fiction.

Comment: Yeah, this was like a flywheel but not actually a wheel - the cart was going around and around the inside wall of the hemisphere.  And it stored far more energy than a conventional flywheel could hold.

Comment: Timothy Zahn wrote [*A Coming of Age*](https://www.benespen.com/journal/2020/11/29/a-coming-of-age-by-timothy-zahn) in which young people have to spin up a flywheel. It's a real flywheel though, and the novel is heavily about psychic powers, so I doubt it's a match.

Comment: Yeah, the one I'm thinking of was hard SF (and almost certainly Analog) - but thanks.

Comment: Damn; I *know* this once, but I can't remember the title. They were using a maglev train in a tunnel for momentum power storage, but some Red Army terrorists smuggled a nuke aboard and there was no way to stop the train in time to disarm it. The trick was "underground resistance movement" - they set up a secondary magnetic loop to lower the train until it bottomed out and smashed to bits, wrecking the bomb also. Hope someone else recognizes this prompt; sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @Steve-Smith, I had a phrase "Underground resistance movement" to Google for, which found a story in Analog that also included the words "kinetic storage ring" - and I was able to run it down  to being Ian Stewart's "[Wall of Death](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47892)" from Analog, October 1990.

Here's a quote:

> A massive vehicle ran round a circular underground track , like a
> wall-of- death motorcyclist, and spare power was fed through electric
> motors to speed it up. To get the power back, the system went into
> reverse, the motors becoming generators. Electrical energy was traded
> for kinetic, back and forth as needed.

I was wrong though - it was a nuclear power plant that used this unique energy storage system (I had thought it was solar or wind).